how to save checkbox value in recyclerview after app exit?
I've been trying to find out how to save checkbox value in recyclerview but i couldn't make it. i tried to find out the method but it's not easy for me. If anyone could help, that'd be great.
about my app : there are textView and checkbox in recyclerview. when textView is clicked, it goes to another fragment. (until this, I made it)  when the checkbox is clicked, i want the chechbox value to be save even after closing app. and now i have problem with the checkbox part. If anyone could help, that'd be great.
public class Beginner_n_use extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RecyclerView recyclerView; 
    ArrayList<kr_style> krlist = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycler_view);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rc_view);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);


        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new n_adapter(krlist, getBaseContext()));
      

        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));
        krlist.add(new kr_style("A"));

    }

public class kr_style {


    private String kr_ver;

    public kr_style(String kr_ver) {

        this.kr_ver = kr_ver;
    }

    public String getKr_ver() {

        return kr_ver;
    }

    public void setKr_ver(String kr_ver) {

        this.kr_ver = kr_ver;
    }



    private boolean getSelected;

    private boolean isSelected;

    public  kr_style(Boolean isSelected){
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected)
    {

        isSelected = selected;
    }

    public boolean getSelected()
    {

        return isSelected;
    }

    private String key_id;
    private String cbStatus;

    public kr_style() {

    }

    public kr_style(String key_id, String cbStatus) {
        this.key_id = key_id;
        this.cbStatus = cbStatus;
    }


    public String getKey_id() {
        return key_id;
    }

    public void setKey_id(String key_id) {
        this.key_id = key_id;
    }

    public String getCbStatus() {
        return cbStatus;
    }

    public void setCbStatus(String cbStatus) {
        this.cbStatus = cbStatus;
    }


}

public class cbDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static String DATABASE_NAME = "forcbDB";
    private static String TABLE_NAME = "cbTable";
    public static String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static String KR_VER = "krVer";
    public static String CB_STATUS = "cbStatus";
    private static String CREATE_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + KEY_ID
            + " TEXT," + KR_VER + " TEXT," + CB_STATUS + " TEXT)";

    public cbDB(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {


    }

    //create empty table
    public void insertEmpty(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        //enter your value
        for (int x = 1; x < 11; x++){
            cv.put(KEY_ID, x);
            cv.put(CB_STATUS, "0");

            long newRowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

        }
    }

    //insert data into database
    public void insertIntoTheDatabase(String krVer, String id, String cb_status){
        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(KR_VER, krVer);
        cv.put(KEY_ID, id);
        cv.put(CB_STATUS, cb_status);

        long newRowId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        Log.d("cbDB Status" , krVer + ", cbstatus — "+cb_status+" — . " + cv); //—작대기???
    }

    //read all data
    public Cursor read_all_data(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + KEY_ID+"="+id+"";
        return db.rawQuery(sql, null, null);
    }

    //remove line from database
    public void remove_cb(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET  " + CB_STATUS+" ='0' WHERE "+KEY_ID+"="+id+"";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        Log.d("remove", id.toString());

    }


    //select all cb list
    public Cursor select_all_cb_list() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+ CB_STATUS+" ='1'";
        return db.rawQuery(sql,null,null);
    }



}

public class n_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<n_adapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final ArrayList<kr_style> krlist;
    private Context context;
    private Intent intent;

    private cbDB cbDB;

    public n_adapter(ArrayList<kr_style> krlist, Context context) {
        this.krlist = krlist;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.kr_view,parent,false);


        cbDB = new cbDB(context);
        //create table on first
        SharedPreferences prefers = context.getSharedPreferences("prefers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean firstStart = prefers.getBoolean("firstStart", true);
        if (firstStart) {
            createTableOnFirstStart();
        }

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {


        holder.textView.setText(krlist.get(position).getKr_ver());

        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),beginner_n_use_jp.class);
                intent.putExtra("number",position);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
        }); //일본어 버전으로 화면 전환

        kr_style kr_style = krlist.get(position);
        holder.chk_box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.chk_box.setChecked(kr_style.getSelected());
        holder.chk_box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

                kr_style.setSelected(isChecked);
                }
        });


        readCursorData(kr_style, holder);
        holder.textView.setText(kr_style.getKr_ver());



    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return krlist.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position){return krlist.get(position);}


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textView;
        public CheckBox chk_box;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.kr_ver);
            chk_box = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);

            //add to cb
            chk_box.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    kr_style kr_style = krlist.get(position);

                    if (kr_style.getCbStatus().equals("0")) {
                        kr_style.setCbStatus("1");
                        cbDB.insertIntoTheDatabase(kr_style.getKr_ver(), kr_style.getKey_id(), kr_style.getCbStatus());
                        chk_box.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chked_box);
                    } else {
                        kr_style.setCbStatus("0");
                        cbDB.remove_cb(kr_style.getKey_id());
                        chk_box.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.empty_box);
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    }

    private void createTableOnFirstStart() {
        cbDB.insertEmpty();

        SharedPreferences prefers = context.getSharedPreferences("prefers", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefers.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private void readCursorData(kr_style kr_style, ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        Cursor cursor = cbDB.read_all_data(kr_style.getKey_id());
        SQLiteDatabase db = cbDB.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                @SuppressLint("Range") String item_cb_status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cbDB.CB_STATUS));
                kr_style.setCbStatus(item_cb_status);

                //check cb status
                if (item_cb_status != null && item_cb_status.equals("1")) {
                    viewHolder.chk_box.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chked_box);
                } else if (item_cb_status != null && item_cb_status.equals("0")) {
                    viewHolder.chk_box.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.empty_box);
                }
            }

        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.isClosed())
                cursor.close();
            db.close();



        }

    }



}

I've been trying to find out how to save checkbox value in recyclerview but i couldn't make it. i tried to find out the method but it's not easy for me. If anyone could help, that'd be great.
